# How can I format two NSDate as a time difference string (e.g. 2days ago) and make it follow the regional formatting of the device?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

Does the standard framework support time difference formatting and create a format that follows the regional settings? I know I can break it to NSDateComponents but then I will have to append the text and create different language support files myself. I'm wondering that there may be a way to formatting the date and make it follows the regional setting simple and similar to this...

`dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle]`

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can turn on relative date formatting by doing:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;
```

this will give you date strings that look like "Yesterday", "Today", "Tomorrow" etc.

if that's not enough, then this might be useful:  http://zetetic.net/code/nsdate-helper

that NSDate category didn't quite work for what i wanted, so i added my own function based on one that was in the category.. seems to work, but no guarantees ;) of course this only gives you a bit of the information - it doesn't give you locale formatting etc.

```
- (NSUInteger)daysAgoAgainstMidnight2 {
    // get a midnight version of ourself:
    NSDateFormatter *mdf = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [mdf setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *midnightMe = [mdf dateFromString:[mdf stringFromDate:self]];
    NSDate *midnightNow = [mdf dateFromString:[mdf stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit)
                                               fromDate:midnightMe                                                             toDate:midnightNow
                                                options:0];
    return [components day];
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't know there is formatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES; I end up with writing everything from scratch. I have to get time difference and compare them manually. It was a real pain but I got everything I want :) (e.g. 2 days ago, in 5 minutes, etc.)