# How can I generate a notification-like time ago strings in iOS?

Tags: ios, time, internationalization, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

Notifications on iOS show how long ago they arrived:

- *"now"*
- *"5m ago"*
- *"1d ago"*

Is there a native way to generate these strings **in an i18n
   friendly way**? (note: *"m"* is not *"minutes"*)

I know about libraries like [YLMoment](https://github.com/yannickl/YLMoment) but none seem to support these *short* grammars.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614543/how-can-i-format-two-nsdate-as-a-time-difference-string-e-g-2days-ago-and-mak?rq=1?

Comment: Thanks @Lasse, I did but it doesn't seem to help generate anything similar to the notification time ago strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into using [NSDateComponentsFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDateComponentsFormatter_class/). For example:

```
let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .Abbreviated
formatter.includesApproximationPhrase = true
formatter.allowedUnits = [.Minute]
formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1

let oldDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -60*60)

print(formatter.stringFromDate(oldDate, toDate: NSDate()))
```

Will print "About 60m" it doesn't provide "ago" though not sure if that's what you're really after.

Comment: You're completely right with the `Abbreviated` unit style, and that `maximumUnitCount` was something I was missing that brings me very close! I can now generate strings like "-10m" "-4h" in an localized way! Unfortunately it seems [the SDK may not have a way to format these negative strings to use "ago" yet](http://www.openradar.appspot.com/17436956)…

Comment: For the record, `includesTimeRemainingPhrase` will transform "-10m" into "-10m remaining"